# Bike Make and Model Recommendations

Tags: mountain-bike, road-bike, commuting-bike, gravel, heavy

I need suggestions for the most economical bike models that can accommodate my weight. I am 5' 8" (172 cm) and weigh 310 lbs (140 kilograms).  I would like to begin riding a bike for exercise and to commute to and from work. I plan to ride mostly on paved roads at least 6 days a week. I would like to ride approximately 50 miles (80 km) per week to start. I'm interested in road bikes as well as other bicycle types.

Comment: Sorry, at bicycles.se, we avoid specific product recommendations.

Comment: Questions seeking product/service/learning material recommendations or item valuations are off-topic because they tend to become obsolete quickly. Instead describe the situation or specific problem you are trying to solve, or try chatting about it in [The Velodrome](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/214/the-velodrome).

Comment: If you take the tour of the site you will be able to locate several questions regarding heavier riders. If reviewing these questions and responses leaves some unanswered questions the community may be able answer your specific concerns.

Comment: Check out the Heavy tag for pre-existing questions that will be of interest to you.   https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heavy   Sadly we can't say something like "buy a Ralonndwinn brand" because such recommendations are highly regional and will be out of date pretty quickly, so they're off-topic for this site.  I'm going to close this question as off topic, don't take it personally.   The linked page has lots of relevance, have a browse.